# How to schedule a job in unix without crontab command?

Tags: unix, cron, job-scheduling

I would like to schedule a URL load balancer check job without crontab command as the crontab usage is blocked for me.  I tried to run the every 1 hour but it is consuming more resources.  Is there any other efficient way to schedule a job without using a crontab command?

Comment: Probably off-topic for Stack Overflow, but you can look at the "at" command. Or perhaps even a loop with a "sleep 3600" in it.

Comment: Short of running a background process that does its thing and then sleeps for (1 hour - however long the job takes)?

Comment: If your job can be defined as script, i offer you to use tloslite, free to 10 jobs, in your case you use one job.

Comment: @serkan: If crontab usage is blocked for this user, does it really seem likely that he can install something like tloslite?

Comment: if java is installed and the user has the right to use java, than yes. It is a simple jar application with some additional libraries. no installation, just extract and use.

Comment: @serkan: I'm not sure if I'm missing something here, or if you are. To get tloslite, or any other program, to run periodically and started by the system, you need to set it up as root, and if "crontab usage is blocked" for the OP, he/she doesn't seem to be root. From the Tlos Lite 1.7.0 installation guide, page 9: "Using the root user; copy tloslite file to /etc/rc.d/init.d [...]"

Comment: Definition in the document is related with registering tloslite as a service. Of course if any previlege needed while executing jobs it applies. Now tloslite is fully open sourced.

Answer (score 5):

Another command that is used for scheduling commands is `at`. Here's a link to the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/at).

For example, if you want to run a command at a given time, you can do

```
at 4pm /path/to/my/command
```

Comment: And then to simulate `cron`, have the last line of your `/path/to/my/command` resubmit itself via `at` for the next run...

Comment: @bstamour What if we can't use `at` either?